# unknown keywords in SQLite CREATE TABLE

Tags: sqlite, create-table

How is `identity` in the following statement interpreted in SQLite?

```
CREATE TABLE [MyID] (
  [ID] int identity NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_MyID_1] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
);
```

I assumed it would have the same meaning as AUTOINCREMENT since it was silently accepted.
Using `.schema MyID` I can see `identity` being preserved.

It looks like `identity` can be anything, like `identityX` and it will behave the same.

What is `identity` stored as(label/tag?) and how is it meant to be used?

Answer (score 1):

> How is identity in the following statement interpreted in SQLite?

For SQLite `identity` means nothing and if it is placed before the `NOT NULL` constraint in the definition of the column then it is totally ignored and the code runs fine.

But, this:

```
[ID] int NOT NULL identity
```

would [throw an error](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mkrxjXH9QyPVruchigeN5Q/0).

Also, the correct way to [define a column as autoincrement in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is with the keyword `INTEGER` which is one of SQLite's storage classes and not `INT` (read more at [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE [MyID] (
  [ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, -- NOT NULL is not needed
  ......
);
```

Comment: It's not totally ignored, it's stored and retrievable by the ´.schema´ command. Does SQLite store unknown words in case they have a meaning in future versions? or are they stored as a comment?

Comment: @hultqvist It is totally ignored means that it does not make any difference if it is there or not. It is stored because this is what SQLite does: it stores the table's definition as it was written. Try: `CREATE TABLE tablename (x something, y hultqvist, z);` It rus fine and it is stored. This does not mean that `something` or `hultqvist` mean anything to SQLite, or they are stored just in case they will mean anything in the future.